# How to insert a row via ajax with NgTable?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

Ok, i´m trying to do something very simple, here is my code:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in $data  | filter:searchText">
```

and i´ve this function, it´s called when i want to generate my table...

```
$scope.init = function (obj) {
      if (isValid(obj)) {
            generateService.sendUrlViaPost(obj.url, obj.params).then(function (response) {
                        $scope.$data = response;

            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                            page: obj.page,
                            count: obj.count,
                        }, {
                            total: $scope.grid.data.length,
                            getData: function ($defer, params) { //$data
                                orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.$data, params.orderBy()) : $scope.$data;
                                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                            }
                        });
});
```

Calling it at my html(it´s working fine)

```
data-ng-init="init({url: '/Professional/GetAll', params: false, page: 1, count: 10})"
```

The problem is when i call it when i submit my form and i want to reload via ajax and insert one row at my ngTable...

```
gridService.init({ url: '/Professional/GetAll', params: false, page: 1, count: 10});
```

Why my ngTable isn´t reloading? I think that the problem is with my ng-repeat because it isn´t reloading my table...

Comment: To reload ngTable: $scope.tableParams.reload();

Comment: yap, i´m already using it, but thanks!